# Postgres GROUP BY id, then show first and last values based on timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in Postgres like so:

| ID | Timestamp | Followers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 100 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 200 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | 202 |
| 2 | 2021-01-03 | 204 |

I want to return a result grouped by the ID, with earliest follower count, and the latest follower count.

So result would be:

| ID | Max Follower | Min Follower |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 100 |
| 2 | 204 | 200 |

The aim is to return the corresponding followers for the earliest timestamp and latest timestamp - as followers can go up and down in the in-between periods.

In MySQL I used a slightly hacky solution:

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(b.followers ORDER BY timestamp ASC),',',1) as old`

Is there a better solution in Postgres?

Comment: I find a column that is named `timestamp` but stores a `date` highly confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, that looks like a simple aggregation:

```
select id,  
       max(followers) as max_follower, 
       min(followers) as min_follower
from the_table
group by id
order by id;
```

Edit:

if you don't want "min" and "max" but "earliest" and "latest" you can do the following:

```
select id,  
       (array_agg(followers order by "timestamp" desc))][1] as latest_follower, 
       (array_agg(followers order by "timestamp"))[1] as earliest_follower
from the_table
group by id
order by id;
```

Comment: Number of follower is not monotonic I guess.  Probably min max prefixes abuses and should more first last?

Comment: This won't return the correct answer, this returns min and max, but not "followers at earliest timestamp" and "followers at latest timestamp" - which aren't necessarily the MIN and MAX

Comment: @dojogeorge: but your sample data does exactly that (and you even named the columns as min and max). If you want the "latest" and "earliest" you can do that by aggregating into an array. See my edit